# youtube-dl, download of all videos in a channel

Tags: youtube-dl, qpython

I'm trying to download all the videos in a channel, using

`youtube-dl -citk -o (location) -f best (URL)`.

But it shows an error, saying output file has conflict with video name. So anyone help me with this. I want to download all the video in that channel and also want to specify the location for it.

Note: I also tried using `ytuser:`, still nothing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your command line parameters don't make any sense (see also [this FAQ entry](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/blob/master/README.md#do-i-always-have-to-pass--citw)). Remove all of the superfluous ones.

In detail:

`-f best` makes youtube-dl download the video file with the best individual quality. For many services, including YouTube, the best quality can only be achieved by downloading a video-only and an audio-only file and combining them. Therefore, this option may *reduce* the quality of the final video, but it no (or only some) postprocessing will be necessary.

`-o (location)` is a useful option, provided the actual option is 
something like `-o "/my/video/directory/%(title)s-%(id)s.%(ext)s"`.

`-k` means to keep the downloaded intermediary files. If you're passing in `-f best`, it does not make any sense, since there will be no intermediary files.

`-t` is equivalent to `-o "%(title)s-%(id)s.%(ext)s"`. Since you have already specified a `-o`, these two options conflict.

`-i` means to silently continue downloading upon errors. This can be a good idea for playlists.

`-c` means to continue started downloads. By default, youtube-dl already does that if it detects that everything is alright (i.e. same format etc.).

To fix your problem, remove all the superfluous and conflicting options and run

```
youtube-dl -i -o (location) (URL)
```

Add `-f best` if you really want to avoid postprocessing.

Comment: Thanks bro, understood what's been dragging. I'm a beginner in Linux, saw those commands in some pages, so I tried didn't worked out.I'll try what you said.

Comment: I need one more detail about ouput location, I'm using qpython in android and I want to save those videos to a folder in sdcard. What would be the syntax for that? I can't understand this. -o "/my/video/directory/%(title)s-%(id)s.%(ext)s"

Comment: @Ashokraj `-o` is a template. `%(title)s` will be replaced by the video title, `%(id)s` by the video ID etc. . See the [documentation](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/blob/master/README.md#output-template) for all available fields. Also replace `/my/video/directory` with the directory of the SD card.